# Testing against non-dominance of discrete distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, order-statistics, stochastic-ordering

I have two discrete distributions $A$ and $B$ with independent draws.

What tests can I use against $H_0$: $A$ does *not* first-order stochastically dominate $B$?

Comment: If you are only seeking a package to do this, that would be off topic here. If you have a statistical question about these tests, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Okay, I have moved this part of my question over to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57967454/testing-against-non-dominance-of-discrete-distributions-in-r-or-stata).

Comment: Can you give some context? What is the application? Sample sizes? A link to your definition of stochastic dominance? Did you have a look at some of [these papers](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ACYBGNRfL_XKSCgp0g9WZCmrJrHA2Nr2MA%3A1568742450331&ei=MhyBXcDzE-HKrgSsnYCYAw&q=stochastic+domination+inference&oq=stochastic+domination+inference&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3342.6135..7236...0.0..0.283.915.8j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i22i30.WSZ4hiEBUJ4&ved=0ahUKEwjA1PuDtdjkAhVhpYsKHawOADMQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)? Also some texts : ...

Comment: ... https://www.amazon.com/Restricted-Statistical-Inference-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471917877/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=order+restricted+statistical&qid=1568742975&s=gateway&sr=8-3